# How to calculate BCR421U LED driver external resistor to my specified current

Tags: led-driver

I am using a [BCR420U](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1901181730_Diodes-Incorporated-BCR421UW6-7_C194382.pdf) as a constant current for an LED indicator, the datasheet does not mention a formula for calculating the external resistor needed for a given current output, all I have is this graph.

[image]

My application uses 12-24 volts DC input and my enable will be tied to the input, so here is my first question. Would my higher enable voltage matter and the graph does not apply anymore?

I want to set my current to 5 mA so is it correct to use 20 ohms?

Comment: @glen_geek oops i have the wrong part, i ment using the 40v version BCR420. when you say 10mA is minimum led current, you mean for this specific driver? because im pretty sure i have lit up leds with less than 10mA of current, as i like them to be slightly dimm

Comment: "I want to set my current to 5 mA so is it correct to use 20 ohms?" -- 20 ohms corresponds to 0.05 A on the graph which is 50 mA.

Comment: @ErikR oh no you are correct, i missed that, i will need something much greater. and it looks like i have to have many resistor vvalues ready to play with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On page 9 of the datasheet it says this:

[image]

So even if you used an infinite value for R_EXT ("absence of an external resistor") you could not expect to get less than 10 mA.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get < 10 mA , you apply PWM pulse on input.

If you do not want to add this complexity, settle on I= 2 to 4 mA  or 3 to 6 mA (depending on mcd of indicator) using just a series R to drop (V+ - Vf)/I=R and don’t bother using this IC. E.g. 2V for R/Y and 3V for B/G/W is close enuf to choose (24-2V)/4mA= 5500 ohm. Or (24-3V)/6mA= 3500 ohm or nearest .

Comment: you gave me an interesting idea, what would happen if i add a series resistor between the ground pin and ground which effectively increases the internal bias resistor

Comment: No that just reduces Vcc by putting default 10mA * R thru it